# Fit table to page width, overlapping rows and columns with tabularx

Tags: tables, tabularx

My table does not fit in the page. I am trying to fit it in my page width. I am a beginner here, so any help would be appreciated.
I tried using rotating head cells and tabularx, but the first row and columns were overlapping. How can I avoid that? Is there a way to fit my table to the whole column width, rather than just being on the right side?

[image: table wdith exceeded]

My code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 10pt, conference]{ieeeconf} 
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{dcolumn}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}

[![\begin{table}
\caption{Small font size, rotated table head cells.}
\small
\advance\tabcolsep-3.5pt
\begin{tabularx}{\hsize}{@{}X l D{.}{.}{-1} D{.}{.}{-1} D{.}{.}{-1} D{.}{.}{-1} D{.}{.}{-1} D{.}{.}{-1} D{.}{.}{-1} D{.}{.}{-1} D{.}{.}{-1} D{.}{.}{-1} D{.}{.}{-1}}\toprule
\rotatebox{90}{Syndrome}         & \rotatebox{90}{22q11} & \rotatebox{90}{Angelman} & \rotatebox{90}{Apert} & \rotatebox{90}{CDL} & \rotatebox{90}{Down} & \rotatebox{90}{FragileX} & \rotatebox{90}{Marfan} & \rotatebox{90}{Progeria} & \rotatebox{90}{Sotos} & \rotatebox{90}{Treacher Collins} & \rotatebox{90}{Turner} & \rotatebox{90}{Williams} \\ \midrule
22q11            & 0     & 0        & 0     & 0   & 0.5  & 0        & 0      & 0        & 0     & 0                & 0      & 0.5      \\ 
Angelman         & 0     & 85.7     & 0     & 4.7 & 0    & 0        & 4.7    & 0        & 0     & 0                & 0      & 4.7      \\ 
Apert            & 0     & 0        & 100   & 0   & 0    & 0        & 0      & 0        & 0     & 0                & 0      & 0        \\ 
CDL              & 0     & 0        & 0     & 96  & 0    & 0        & 0      & 0        & 0     & 0                & 0      & 4.7      \\ 
Down             & 0     & 0        & 0     & 0   & 94.7 & 0        & 5.2    & 0        & 0     & 0                & 0      & 0        \\ 
FragileX         & 0     & 17.6     & 0     & 0   & 76.4 & 0        & 0      & 0        & 0     & 0                & 0      & 5.8      \\ 
Marfan           & 0     & 0        & 0     & 0   & 0    & 0        & 100    & 0        & 0     & 0                & 0      & 0        \\ 
Progeria         & 0     & 0        & 0     & 0   & 0    & 0.5      & 0      & 0.25     & 0.25  & 0                & 0      & 0        \\ 
Sotos            & 0     & 0        & 0     & 0   & 0    & 0        & 0      & 0        & 100   & 0                & 0      & 0        \\ 
Treacher Collins & 0     & 0        & 0     & 0   & 0    & 0.5      & 0      & 0        & 0     & 0                & 0.5    & 0        \\ 
Turner           & 0     & 8.6      & 0     & 4.3 & 0    & 4.3      & 0      & 0        & 0     & 0                & 0      & 82.6     \\ 
Williams         &       &          &       &     &      &          &        &          &       &                  &        &          \\ \bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}][1]][1]
\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: I have made changes.

Comment: By breaking the table into two seperate parts, would it fit the whole page width? I am sorry, but I am still a beginner here. I don't know how to use table* environment. Could you please help me out there? @Mico

Comment: @ZER-0-NE - Please see the answer I just posted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to reduce the font size, further reduce the amount of intercolumn whitespace, and give up on the idea of aligning the numbers in columns 2 thru 13 on their decimal markers -- the text column simply isn't wide enough for such a luxury.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 10pt, conference]{IEEEconf} 
\usepackage{booktabs,tabularx,graphicx}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\caption{Small font size, rotated table head cells.}
\footnotesize  % not "\small"
\setlength\tabcolsep{2pt} % default value: 6pt
\begin{tabularx}{\hsize}{@{} X *{12}{c} @{}}
\toprule
 \rotatebox{90}{Syndrome}  & \rotatebox{90}{22q11} 
& \rotatebox{90}{Angelman} & \rotatebox{90}{Apert} 
& \rotatebox{90}{CDL}      & \rotatebox{90}{Down} 
& \rotatebox{90}{FragileX} & \rotatebox{90}{Marfan} 
& \rotatebox{90}{Progeria} & \rotatebox{90}{Sotos} 
& \rotatebox{90}{Treacher Collins} 
& \rotatebox{90}{Turner}   & \rotatebox{90}{Williams} \\ 
\midrule
22q11            & 0     & 0        & 0     & 0   & 0.5  & 0        & 0      & 0        & 0     & 0                & 0      & 0.5      \\ 
Angelman         & 0     & 85.7     & 0     & 4.7 & 0    & 0        & 4.7    & 0        & 0     & 0                & 0      & 4.7      \\ 
Apert            & 0     & 0        & 100   & 0   & 0    & 0        & 0      & 0        & 0     & 0                & 0      & 0        \\ 
CDL              & 0     & 0        & 0     & 96  & 0    & 0        & 0      & 0        & 0     & 0                & 0      & 4.7      \\ 
Down             & 0     & 0        & 0     & 0   & 94.7 & 0        & 5.2    & 0        & 0     & 0                & 0      & 0        \\ 
FragileX         & 0     & 17.6     & 0     & 0   & 76.4 & 0        & 0      & 0        & 0     & 0                & 0      & 5.8      \\ 
Marfan           & 0     & 0        & 0     & 0   & 0    & 0        & 100    & 0        & 0     & 0                & 0      & 0        \\ 
Progeria         & 0     & 0        & 0     & 0   & 0    & 0.5      & 0      & 0.25     & 0.25  & 0                & 0      & 0        \\ 
Sotos            & 0     & 0        & 0     & 0   & 0    & 0        & 0      & 0        & 100   & 0                & 0      & 0        \\ 
Treacher Collins & 0     & 0        & 0     & 0   & 0    & 0.5      & 0      & 0        & 0     & 0                & 0.5    & 0        \\ 
Turner           & 0     & 8.6      & 0     & 4.3 & 0    & 4.3      & 0      & 0        & 0     & 0                & 0      & 82.6     \\ 
Williams     & x & x & x & x & x & x & x & x & x & x & x & x \\ 
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```